# Questions to Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, backup, log-shipping

I'm planning my database backup strategy and came across the continuous archiving concept of PostgreSQL which is exactly what I'm looking for.

I have two questions on this.

I'm planning to mount the WAL file archive directory to an external NFS storage space (e.g. `/mnt/nfs/archivedir/`). I read that this log shipping is asynchronous by default. Does that mean that I don't have any performance issues on this?

As I understand it right, I must not loose any of the WAL segment files, right? But what if any file is corrupt? Can I recover the database ever again then? I guess that a lot of things can go wrong, because what happens when the server is suddenly turned off, or what if the NFS is suddenly not reachable, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the pg_receivewal utility on the server that will receive the logs, it will help you with this problem.

see more at:

[pg_receivewal - Doc official](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgreceivewal.html)